# Remove lines that have duplicate entry in the first column

Tags: shell, csv, awk, filter, duplicates

I want to filter my file (tab delimited) by removing the duplicate entries in the first column in each line.

I tried this:

```
cut -f1 filename.txt | sort | uniq -u > filename_filtered.txt
```

But this only prints out the first column of the file, is there anyway to filter the first column but print out the entire filtered file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it:

```
awk '!a[$1]++' file
```

It keeps track of the fields, printing a line just if its first field haven't appeared yet.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
test    hello   bye
test    bye     hello
another thing   here
how     how     how
another blab    bla
text    text    text

$ awk '!a[$1]++' a
test    hello   bye
another thing   here
how     how     how
text    text    text
```

Comment: Good to read that :) Consider accepting the answer if you are done.